# Create legend click events on multiple matplotlib.pyplot subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have several `matplolib.pyplot` figures. Each has a legend, and what I want is that clicking the line on the legend hides the line in the figure. The click event handling was found here: https://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/legend_picking.html

This works fine when there is only one figure, but when there are more than one, it only works with the last figure. When I click on the legend of another figure, I get no exception or warning, but nothing happens.

Here is an example code which features this issue:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(0,10,1)
    b = np.arange(0,20,2)
    c = np.arange(0,5,.5)
    d = np.arange(-1,9,1)

    lined = {}

    for var1, var2 in [(a,b), (c,d)]:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        line1, = ax.plot(var1, label="l1")
        line2, = ax.plot(var2, label="l2")
        leg = fig.legend([line1, line2], ["l1", "l2"])
        legl1, legl2 = leg.get_lines()
        legl1.set_picker(5)
        lined[legl1] = line1
        legl2.set_picker(5)
        lined[legl2] = line2

        def onpick(event, figu):
            legl = event.artist
            origl = lined[legl]
            vis = not origl.get_visible()
            origl.set_visible(vis)
            if vis:
                legl.set_alpha(1.0)
            else:
                legl.set_alpha(0.2)
            figu.canvas.draw()

        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', lambda ev: onpick(ev, fig))
    plt.show()
```

How can I make the click event work on the first figure too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found a solution that is a bit simpler than [ImportanceOfBeingErnest's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56274730/8837809) and makes more sense than [Leporello's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56271197/8837809) because it only defines the function `onpick` once, and is the same for every figure.

Since the reference to the figure is only needed for the `canvas`, and the `canvas` is found in the `event`, the following code works perfectly:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(0,10,1)
    b = np.arange(0,20,2)
    c = np.arange(0,5,.5)
    d = np.arange(-1,9,1)

    lined = {}
    def onpick(event):
            legl = event.artist
            origl = lined[legl]
            vis = not origl.get_visible()
            origl.set_visible(vis)
            if vis:
                legl.set_alpha(1.0)
            else:
                legl.set_alpha(0.2)
            event.canvas.draw()

    for var1, var2 in [(a,b), (c,d)]:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        line1, = ax.plot(var1, label="l1")
        line2, = ax.plot(var2, label="l2")
        leg = fig.legend([line1, line2], ["l1", "l2"])
        legl1, legl2 = leg.get_lines()
        legl1.set_picker(5)
        lined[legl1] = line1
        legl2.set_picker(5)
        lined[legl2] = line2

        fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is given by https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures. I must admit I do not understand it entirely myself, but it gives the trick to solve it: use a default argument.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(0,10,1)
b = np.arange(0,20,2)
c = np.arange(0,5,.5)
d = np.arange(-1,9,1)

lined = {}

for var1, var2 in [(a,b), (c,d)]:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    line1, = ax.plot(var1, label="l1")
    line2, = ax.plot(var2, label="l2")
    leg = fig.legend([line1, line2], ["l1", "l2"])
    legl1, legl2 = leg.get_lines()
    legl1.set_picker(5)
    lined[legl1] = line1
    legl2.set_picker(5)
    lined[legl2] = line2

    def onpick(event, figu=fig):
        legl = event.artist
        origl = lined[legl]
        vis = not origl.get_visible()
        origl.set_visible(vis)
        if vis:
            legl.set_alpha(1.0)
        else:
            legl.set_alpha(0.2)
        figu.canvas.draw()

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)  # no need for a lambda
plt.show()
```

As mentioned, that solution is kind of hacky. Compare the seemingly equivalent

```
# works
    def onpick(event, figu=fig):
        (...)
        figu.canvas.draw()  # using a default arg equal to fig
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
```

vs.

```
# fails as described
    def onpick(event):
        (...)
        fig.canvas.draw()  # using fig from main loop directly
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
```

Comment: I've added the missing explanation

Answer (score 1):

[@Leporello's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56271197/2988730) is complete in terms of diagnosis and solution. Here is the full explanation:

The line `lambda ev: onpick(ev, fig)` creates a function object that references the names `onpick` and `fig`. The function gets called *after* the loop ends, after `plt.show()` runs.

The names `onpick` and `fig` are non-local, so it searches in the module namespace. By the time the listener is invoked, `onpick` refers to the last function created, and `fig` refers to the figure created in the last iteration of the loop.

Leporello's suggestion of default arguments is probably the most elegant way of doing this. It works because the entire `def` statement is evaluated at once. A `def` creates a function object with the code block inside it, and assigns references to the defaults right then and there. That means that you end up setting the callback to the correct function object, and whatever `fig` was inside the loop, will be what `figu` points to.

Any operation that binds the names `onpick` and `fig` to something in the local namesapace of the callback, or any other namespace created in the loop, will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect application where using a class may be beneficial. It would allow to store the respective figure in an instance variable and use it in the methods of the class.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class MyPlot():
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.lined = {}
        self.fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        line1, = ax.plot(var1, label="l1")
        line2, = ax.plot(var2, label="l2")
        leg = self.fig.legend([line1, line2], ["l1", "l2"])
        legl1, legl2 = leg.get_lines()
        legl1.set_picker(5)
        self.lined[legl1] = line1
        legl2.set_picker(5)
        self.lined[legl2] = line2
        self.cid = self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.onpick)

    def onpick(self, event):
        legl = event.artist
        if legl in self.lined:
            origl = self.lined[legl]
            vis = not origl.get_visible()
            origl.set_visible(vis)
            if vis:
                legl.set_alpha(1.0)
            else:
                legl.set_alpha(0.2)
            self.fig.canvas.draw()


a = np.arange(0,10,1)
b = np.arange(0,20,2)
c = np.arange(0,5,.5)
d = np.arange(-1,9,1)

plots = [MyPlot(*var) for var in [(a,b), (c,d)]]

plt.show()
```